# Client Lists on website - Best practice: hyperlink to client or static image?

Tags: website-design, image, seo

I have been looking for some supporting research on this with no avail, We are looking to update our client's page that displays logos. We currently have each logo and a hyperlink to each client, however notice alot of corporate websites display a static image with all logos on this.

[image]

From an SEO perpective I can see the benefit of having each logo and an outbound link, but in terms of speed and page size it will be somewhat bloated and decrease performance.

Is there a definitive answer, or is this purely subjective?

Comment: adding link shouldn't significantly add to the page weight. I'd included the links.

Comment: Also, while there may be a definitive answer, it's most likely subjective, and in this case, highly dependent on the particular objective you're after.

Answer (score 1):

**Do you have client case studies hosted on your site?**

Then yes. You would put a logo or image to link to the case study which in turn links to the client company. For example, http://www.sapientnitro.com/en-us.html#work/featured links to a detailed view of their client solutions along with their logos. Another example is http://phonegap.com/app/. This gives a better idea about your work for that client.

Phonegap shows the prominent clients with their case studies with a see more link that lists almost all their clients.

I have also seen many websites (http://www.kony.com/) showing only their prominent clients' logos on the front page that links to an 'About customers' page instead of simply showing a page riddled only with logos.